# array_values() does not display correct values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

This is my array :

```
array (size=12)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'mon' => string '2018-01-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'nb_argus' => string '29' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'mon' => string '2018-02-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'nb_argus' => string '21' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'mon' => string '2018-03-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'nb_argus' => string '34' (length=2)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'mon' => string '2018-04-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'nb_argus' => string '18' (length=2)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'mon' => string '2018-05-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'nb_argus' => string '25' (length=2)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'mon' => string '2018-06-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'nb_argus' => string '17' (length=2)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'mon' => string '2018-07-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'nb_argus' => string '23' (length=2)
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      'mon' => string '2018-08-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'nb_argus' => string '8' (length=1)
  8 => 
    array (size=2)
      'mon' => string '2018-09-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'nb_argus' => string '14' (length=2)
  9 => 
    array (size=2)
      'mon' => string '2018-10-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'nb_argus' => string '0' (length=1)
  10 => 
    array (size=2)
      'mon' => string '2018-11-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'nb_argus' => string '0' (length=1)
  11 => 
    array (size=2)
      'mon' => string '2018-12-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'nb_argus' => string '0' (length=1)
```

I'm simply trying to display each of  the 'nb_argus' values inside a foreach loop, but can't use the STRING to point at, i need to use an index, this is my code :

```
foreach ($array_12_months  as $key => $tab) {

        foreach($tab as $row2 => $tab2){

            $tab2 = array_values($tab2);
            echo $tab2[1] . " my complete nb_argus value <br/>";
        }
    }
```

It doesnt work, and instead of displaying 29 for example, it displays 2 !

instead of displaying 21 , it displays only one character : 2

I really can't find any solution, have tried plenty of things, i can't access to my nb_argus values, while i'm using array_values(), it doesnt work, please help

Is it because the nb_argus is a string that it is not working ? I can't find any solution.

Comment: Looks like you are using too many loops.

Answer (score 2):

Use array_column and extract only the 'nb_argus' to a flat array and echo them.

```
$nb_argus = array_column($arr, 'nb_argus');
foreach($nb_argus as $nb){
    echo $nb . " ";
}
```

Or you can implode the array and echo them like:

```
$nb_argus = array_column($arr, 'nb_argus');
echo implode(" ", $nb_argus);
```

Comment: No i cant use nb_argus i need to use an index instead, because nb_argus is not always the same

Comment: How does it change? Can you give a sample what it looks like if it changes?

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to access the index by number, instead of using the `nb_argus` key, then you can use:

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    $values = array_values($item);
    echo $values[1] . " my complete nb_argus value <br/>";
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you, there are 12 values per month, and i need to do a math operation on each of them, by 'gluing' another 12 months array ... ... I'm trying this now

Comment: 'gluing' is not a math term I have heard of before. What are you actually trying to do? Also your data shows 12 values per **year**, not per month.

Comment: Instead of using `echo`, add all data to an array, then use some function like `array_map` or `array_reduce`